# Why is Surefire running these JUnit tests sequentially instead of in parallel?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm experienced with software dev generally and Java specifically, but the projects using JUnit that I've worked on in the past have all been set up by others. I'm on the hook for sorting out an issue with our testing now, and I need some specific direction from JUnit experts.

To diagnose the issue with my real codebase, I'm experimenting with a small project. Like the real project, it uses Maven to build and the Surefire plugin to execute JUnit tests.

The project itself has one simple method that writes some entries in the log (including details of the current thread and a token from the caller) and then sleeps for a specified amount of time before returning.

I have 2 test classes, each with 2 test methods, and each of them hits that same sleeping method some number of times. All test cases are executing sequentially, in the context of the main thread. Here is how Surefire is configured:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <parallelMavenExecution>true</parallelMavenExecution>
        <parallel>all</parallel>
        <threadCount>16</threadCount>
        <threadCountSuites>4</threadCountSuites>
        <threadCountClasses>4</threadCountClasses>
        <threadCountMethods>8</threadCountMethods>
        <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've specified that everything should run in parallel, and a count of 16 threads on a machine with 16 virtual cores. When I run the test target using maven, I get output like the following:

```
Z:\Workspaces\Java\JUnitTesting>\Workspaces\Java\MVN\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin\mvn -T 1C test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the MultiThreadedBuilder implementation with a thread count of 16
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.example:JUnitTesting >----------------------
[INFO] Building JUnitTesting 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ JUnitTesting ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ JUnitTesting ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ JUnitTesting ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory Z:\Workspaces\Java\JUnitTesting\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ JUnitTesting ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ JUnitTesting ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running SecondSleeperTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.140 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:12 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.BeforeAll()
2021-12-17 10:41:05.156 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:17 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.BeforeEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:05.156 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:29 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest() enter
2021-12-17 10:41:05.156 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 20, id: 1, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.191 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 20, id: 1, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.191 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 40, id: 2, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.238 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 40, id: 2, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.238 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 60, id: 3, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.300 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 60, id: 3, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.300 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 80, id: 4, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.394 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 80, id: 4, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.394 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 100, id: 5, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.504 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 100, id: 5, message: SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:05.504 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:33 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.IncrementalTest() exit
2021-12-17 10:41:05.504 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:38 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.AfterEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:05.504 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:17 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.BeforeEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:05.504 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:22 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.BasicTest() enter
2021-12-17 10:41:05.504 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 1000, id: 99, message: SecondSleeperTest.BasicTest
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 1000, id: 99, message: SecondSleeperTest.BasicTest
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:24 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.BasicTest() exit
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:38 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.AfterEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  SecondSleeperTest:43 - main:1 - SecondSleeperTest.AfterAll()
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.598 s - in SecondSleeperTest
[INFO] Running SleeperTest
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  SleeperTest:12 - main:1 - SleeperTest.BeforeAll()
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  SleeperTest:17 - main:1 - SleeperTest.BeforeEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  SleeperTest:29 - main:1 - SleeperTest.IncrementalTest() enter
2021-12-17 10:41:06.519 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 100, id: 1, message: SleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:06.630 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 100, id: 1, message: SleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:06.630 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 200, id: 2, message: SleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:06.833 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 200, id: 2, message: SleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:06.833 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 300, id: 3, message: SleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:07.145 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 300, id: 3, message: SleeperTest.IncrementalTest
2021-12-17 10:41:07.145 EST INFO  SleeperTest:33 - main:1 - SleeperTest.IncrementalTest() exit
2021-12-17 10:41:07.145 EST INFO  SleeperTest:38 - main:1 - SleeperTest.AfterEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:07.145 EST INFO  SleeperTest:17 - main:1 - SleeperTest.BeforeEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:07.145 EST INFO  SleeperTest:22 - main:1 - SleeperTest.BasicTest() enter
2021-12-17 10:41:07.145 EST INFO  Sleeper:14 - main:1 - SleepVerbose - about to sleep. duration: 5000, id: 99, message: SleeperTest.BasicTest
2021-12-17 10:41:12.151 EST INFO  Sleeper:21 - main:1 - main:1 SleepVerbose - just woke up. duration: 5000, id: 99, message: SleeperTest.BasicTest
2021-12-17 10:41:12.151 EST INFO  SleeperTest:24 - main:1 - SleeperTest.BasicTest() exit
2021-12-17 10:41:12.151 EST INFO  SleeperTest:38 - main:1 - SleeperTest.AfterEach()
2021-12-17 10:41:12.151 EST INFO  SleeperTest:43 - main:1 - SleeperTest.AfterAll()
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.632 s - in SleeperTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.674 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-17T10:41:12-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, the builder indicates in the logs that it's using 16 threads as specified on the command line with the argument "-T 1C". But the timing, the order of entries in the log, and the content of the logs (identifying thread name & id as main:1) all show that all JUnit tests are running in the same thread. To make sure that the "configuration" block in my pom.xml is not being completely ignored, I ran mvn with the --debug option. Here's a relevant excerpt from those logs that shows that the config is being picked up:

```
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <additionalClasspathElements>${maven.test.additionalClasspath}</additionalClasspathElements>
  <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <childDelegation default-value="false">${childDelegation}</childDelegation>
  <classesDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <classpathDependencyExcludes>${maven.test.dependency.excludes}</classpathDependencyExcludes>
  <debugForkedProcess>${maven.surefire.debug}</debugForkedProcess>
  <dependenciesToScan>${dependenciesToScan}</dependenciesToScan>
  <disableXmlReport default-value="false">${disableXmlReport}</disableXmlReport>
  <enableAssertions default-value="true">${enableAssertions}</enableAssertions>
  <enableProcessChecker>${surefire.enableProcessChecker}</enableProcessChecker>
  <encoding default-value="${project.reporting.outputEncoding}">${surefire.encoding}</encoding>
  <excludedEnvironmentVariables>${surefire.excludedEnvironmentVariables}</excludedEnvironmentVariables>
  <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
  <excludesFile>${surefire.excludesFile}</excludesFile>
  <failIfNoSpecifiedTests>${surefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests}</failIfNoSpecifiedTests>
  <failIfNoTests>${failIfNoTests}</failIfNoTests>
  <forkCount default-value="1">${forkCount}</forkCount>
  <forkMode default-value="once">${forkMode}</forkMode>
  <forkNode>${surefire.forkNode}</forkNode>
  <forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds default-value="30">${surefire.exitTimeout}</forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>
  <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>${surefire.timeout}</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
  <groups>${groups}</groups>
  <includesFile>${surefire.includesFile}</includesFile>
  <junitArtifactName default-value="junit:junit">${junitArtifactName}</junitArtifactName>
  <jvm>${jvm}</jvm>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <objectFactory>${objectFactory}</objectFactory>
  <parallel>all</parallel>
  <parallelMavenExecution default-value="${session.parallel}">true</parallelMavenExecution>
  <parallelOptimized default-value="true">${parallelOptimized}</parallelOptimized>
  <parallelTestsTimeoutForcedInSeconds>${surefire.parallel.forcedTimeout}</parallelTestsTimeoutForcedInSeconds>
  <parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>${surefire.parallel.timeout}</parallelTestsTimeoutInSeconds>
  <perCoreThreadCount default-value="true">false</perCoreThreadCount>
  <pluginArtifactMap>${plugin.artifactMap}</pluginArtifactMap>
  <pluginDescriptor default-value="${plugin}"/>
  <printSummary default-value="true">${surefire.printSummary}</printSummary>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <projectArtifactMap>${project.artifactMap}</projectArtifactMap>
  <projectBuildDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <projectRemoteRepositories default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <redirectTestOutputToFile default-value="false">${maven.test.redirectTestOutputToFile}</redirectTestOutputToFile>
  <remoteRepositories default-value="${project.pluginArtifactRepositories}"/>
  <reportFormat default-value="brief">${surefire.reportFormat}</reportFormat>
  <reportNameSuffix default-value="">${surefire.reportNameSuffix}</reportNameSuffix>
  <reportsDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports"/>
  <rerunFailingTestsCount default-value="0">${surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount}</rerunFailingTestsCount>
  <reuseForks default-value="true">${reuseForks}</reuseForks>
  <runOrder default-value="filesystem">${surefire.runOrder}</runOrder>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <shutdown default-value="exit">${surefire.shutdown}</shutdown>
  <skip default-value="false">${maven.test.skip}</skip>
  <skipAfterFailureCount default-value="0">${surefire.skipAfterFailureCount}</skipAfterFailureCount>
  <skipExec>${maven.test.skip.exec}</skipExec>
  <skipTests default-value="false">${skipTests}</skipTests>
  <suiteXmlFiles>${surefire.suiteXmlFiles}</suiteXmlFiles>
  <systemPropertiesFile>${surefire.systemPropertiesFile}</systemPropertiesFile>
  <tempDir default-value="surefire">${tempDir}</tempDir>
  <test>${test}</test>
  <testClassesDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
  <testFailureIgnore default-value="false">${maven.test.failure.ignore}</testFailureIgnore>
  <testNGArtifactName default-value="org.testng:testng">${testNGArtifactName}</testNGArtifactName>
  <testSourceDirectory default-value="${project.build.testSourceDirectory}"/>
  <threadCount>16</threadCount>
  <threadCountClasses default-value="0">4</threadCountClasses>
  <threadCountMethods default-value="0">8</threadCountMethods>
  <threadCountSuites default-value="0">4</threadCountSuites>
  <trimStackTrace default-value="true">${trimStackTrace}</trimStackTrace>
  <useFile default-value="true">${surefire.useFile}</useFile>
  <useManifestOnlyJar default-value="true">${surefire.useManifestOnlyJar}</useManifestOnlyJar>
  <useModulePath default-value="true">${surefire.useModulePath}</useModulePath>
  <useSystemClassLoader default-value="true">${surefire.useSystemClassLoader}</useSystemClassLoader>
  <useUnlimitedThreads default-value="false">${useUnlimitedThreads}</useUnlimitedThreads>
  <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
</configuration>

snip...

[DEBUG]   (s) reportFormat = brief
[DEBUG]   (s) reportsDirectory = Z:\Workspaces\Java\JUnitTesting\target\surefire-reports
[DEBUG]   (f) rerunFailingTestsCount = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) reuseForks = true
[DEBUG]   (s) runOrder = filesystem
[DEBUG]   (s) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@673ffa09
[DEBUG]   (f) shutdown = exit
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipAfterFailureCount = 0
[DEBUG]   (s) skipTests = false
[DEBUG]   (s) suiteXmlFiles = []
[DEBUG]   (s) tempDir = surefire
[DEBUG]   (s) testClassesDirectory = Z:\Workspaces\Java\JUnitTesting\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   (s) testFailureIgnore = false
[DEBUG]   (s) testNGArtifactName = org.testng:testng
[DEBUG]   (s) testSourceDirectory = Z:\Workspaces\Java\JUnitTesting\src\test\java
[DEBUG]   (s) threadCount = 16
[DEBUG]   (s) threadCountClasses = 4
[DEBUG]   (s) threadCountMethods = 8
[DEBUG]   (s) threadCountSuites = 4
[DEBUG]   (s) trimStackTrace = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useFile = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useManifestOnlyJar = true
[DEBUG]   (f) useModulePath = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useSystemClassLoader = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useUnlimitedThreads = false
[DEBUG]   (s) workingDirectory = Z:\Workspaces\Java\JUnitTesting
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious - any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: First remove the dependency within the plugin area...only add your appropriate dependency in your dependency are ... https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html

Comment: Can you explain from where you have got: `<parallelMavenExecution>...</parallelMavenExecution>`? Also start only with `<forkCount>3</forkCount>` nothing else at the beginning...Furthermore the `<threadCountSuites>..</threadCountSuites>` is JUnit 4.x based...not JUnit Jupiter ...(aka JUnit 5.) and finally can you use a more recent version of JUnit Jupiter (5.8.2) ....also the unit test you are executing can you please show the code it ...

Comment: I added the ```parallelMavenExecution``` item after running ```mvn --debug``` and seeing that it was ```false``` by default in those logs. Since it seemed like it could be relevant, I explicitly set it to true in the config.

Comment: ```forkCount``` is for the number of JVM instances to launch - I only want 1, executing multiple tests in parallel via separate threads.

Comment: That does not help..I suggest you to start with a simple example to identify the problem..but you seemed to be not interested in being helped. Another attempt. Please remove all configurations and deps as suggest by me and put only the configuration into surefire as I suggested. For example threadCountClasses is JUnit 4 based an not JUnit Jupiter based...

Comment: It would also being helpful to see the unit test as I mentioned earlier...